# Why is it valid to not return an object from setState updater?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, just a question on `setState()` method.
I know that `setState()` can takes a function as:

```
handleClick() {
  return this.setState(previousState => {
     return { count: previousState.count + 1 }
  });
}
```

But I also this code in a textbook:

```
...
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      errors: {},
      dirty: {},
      formSubmitted: false,
      getMessagesForField: this.getMessagesForField
   }
}

handleChange = (ev) => {
   let name = ev.target.name;
   this.setState(state => state.dirty[name] = true);
}
```

how come the function doesn't need to return a new state object as:

```
this.setState(state => return {...});
```

I always get told that `setState()` need to return an object regardless of the parameter is just a new state object or a function?

Comment: Single line arrow functions have their `return` statement implicit. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @Dupocas I know without curly braces {} arrow function returns implicitly, but in my case, it just return a boolean value true, which is still not a object?

Comment: @Dupocas  but the code actually works, which means that setState can still takes a function that doesn't return a state object?

Comment: I'll post an answer

Comment: @Dupocas waitingfor your answer

Comment: There is actually a lot of caveats. I'm working on it hahhaha

Comment: Not focusing on arrow function, but as the name suggests, `setState` is a setter function. Setters accept values and update private variables but do not return a value. for more info: refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was surprised with the amount of concepts under the hood here. That is actually a really good question!

**One line arrow functions have their `return` statement implicit**

```
this.setState(state => state.dirty[name] = true)
```

Is the equivalent for

```
this.setState(state =>{
    return state.dirty[name] = true
})
```

**Returning an assignment is the same of returning the result of the assignment**

```
const foo = () =>{
    let counter = 0
    return counter = counter + 1
}

console.log(foo()) // 1
```

Therefore

```
this.setState(state => state.dirty[name] = true)
```

Is equivalent of

```
this.setState(state =>{
    state.dirty[name] = true
    return true
})
```

Here is where it becomes unintuitive. Although React's docs are explicitly saying that

> setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.

But the only validation regarding the returned value from the `updater` function is if it aren't `null` or `undefined`. Take a look at `setState` definition

```
Component.prototype.setState = function(partialState, callback) {
  invariant(
    typeof partialState === 'object' ||
      typeof partialState === 'function' ||
      partialState == null,
    'setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a ' +
      'function which returns an object of state variables.',
  );
  this.updater.enqueueSetState(this, partialState, callback, 'setState');
};
```

So calling `this.setState(state => true)` actually satisfies the second condition of `invariant`, after all `typeof state => true === 'function'`. So the update is enqueued. Now let's take a look at `enqueueSetState`

```
  enqueueSetState(inst, payload, callback) {
    const fiber = getInstance(inst);
    const currentTime = requestCurrentTimeForUpdate();
    const suspenseConfig = requestCurrentSuspenseConfig();
    const expirationTime = computeExpirationForFiber(
      currentTime,
      fiber,
      suspenseConfig,
    );

    const update = createUpdate(expirationTime, suspenseConfig);
    update.payload = payload;
    if (callback !== undefined && callback !== null) {
      if (__DEV__) {
        warnOnInvalidCallback(callback, 'setState');
      }
      update.callback = callback;
    }

    enqueueUpdate(fiber, update);
    scheduleWork(fiber, expirationTime);
  }
```

Our `updater` is now called `payload`. This `payload` is beeing passed to construct an `Update` object which defined `payload`'s type as `any`:

```
export type Update<State> = {
  expirationTime: ExpirationTime,
  suspenseConfig: null | SuspenseConfig,

  tag: 0 | 1 | 2 | 3,
  payload: any,
  callback: (() => mixed) | null,

  next: Update<State> | null,
  nextEffect: Update<State> | null,

  //DEV only
  priority?: ReactPriorityLevel,
};
```

So there is actually nothing wrong until now, let's move on, now the `update` enqueued

```
enqueueUpdate(fiber, update)
```

Now inside `enqueueUpdate` we have the following line (I'm pasting only the revelant code, the actual definition is waay bigger)

```
if (typeof payload === 'function')
    partialState = payload.call(instance, prevState, nextProps)
```

And finally

```
  if (partialState === null || partialState === undefined) {
    // Null and undefined are treated as no-ops.
    return prevState;
  }
  // Merge the partial state and the previous state.
  return Object.assign({}, prevState, partialState);
```

So the final step of setting the state is merge previous and new state

```
return Object.assign({}, prevState, partialState)
```

Which is the equivalent to

```
return Object.assign({}, prevState, true)
```

Which results in `prevState` itself!

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you use arrow function without curly braces {} return is implicit 
So the following is actually returning an object as state.dirty is an object

```
handleChange = (ev) => {
 let name = ev.target.name;
 this.setState(state => state.dirty[name] = true);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: sorry, isn't your code exact the same as mine? and also, I know without curly braces {} arrow function returns implicitly, but in my case, it just return a boolean value true, which is still not a object?

Comment: @Dupocas Can you please explain a bit, would the object state.dirty be returned after the assignment ?

Comment: @Dupocas  yes, that what I don't get. setState is supposed to take an object if the parameter is an object, if the parameter is a function, that function should return an object,but in my case, it just return an assignment, which is invalid?

Comment: when you return an assignment the `return` value is the  property / variable which is being assigned.